# SQL Server Spatial Distance of Two Points from Google Map

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, spatial

I'm getting to know SQL Server Spatial datatype. As a simple test, I picked two points on Google Map and wrote down the distance. To be exact:

```
lat = 35.701657, long = 51.419479
lat = 35.701737, long = 51.425934
Distance = 587.18 m
```

Okay, but running the following query in SQL Server 2012 yields a different (and meaningless, to be honest) result:

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
DECLARE @h geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.425934 35.701737)', 4326);
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.419479 35.701657)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h)

Result = 0.00645549572069735
```

I know that Spatial datatype gets longitude before latitude (as in my example) and I've used 4326 as SRID (which is seemingly used by Google and other map services) and should return meters.

What Google Map calculates is correct. How can I calculate the same number in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) spatial data type instead of [geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx).
Try this.

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.425934 35.701737)', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.419479 35.701657)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h)
```

Results:
584.257975718466

**edit:**  the 3m difference could be attributed to the way google maps snaps to the road to calculate distance (there is a small bend in the road segment), while SQL Server will get the closest distance in a straight line.

Comment: I can't believe how I made that mistake. Thanks very much.